# Can I use ClassId in tabbedpage to differentiate their content

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm trying to use the same page for 3 tabs in TabbedPage. But each tab has to display different data in the listview. Is there a way to set a parameter for each tab?

Example

```
    <local:Sales Title="Pending" 
                 Icon="ic_shortcut_home.png"
                 ClassId="pending"/>

    <local:Sales Title="Posted" 
                 Icon="ic_shortcut_home.png"
                 ClassId="posted"/>

    <local:Sales Title="Uploaded" 
                 Icon="ic_shortcut_home.png"
                 ClassId="uploaded"/>
```

I tried using ClassId, and Title to get their difference but I'm having trouble retrieving the ClassId in the Sales class constructor, are there any other ways to get the output I want?

```
        public Sales()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
            salesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Head>();
            initLvw();
            Console.WriteLine(Title); //returns null
            Console.WriteLine(ClassId); // returns null
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load data in [OnAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms) method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Console.WriteLine(ClassId + "OnAppearing");

    BindingContext = this;
    salesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Head>();
    initLvw();

}
```

Or load data with a little `delay` in constructor:

```
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        Console.WriteLine(ClassId + "AboutPage");

        BindingContext = this;
        salesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Head>();
        initLvw();
    });
}
```